# What parts of the computation graph does Tensorflow optimize?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, graph

I have the following situation: I have a model X that is shared between three more models A, B, C and training samples belong to one of the models A, B, C.

Depending on the model a training sample belongs to, I multiply the individual loss either with 0 (doesn't belong to it) or 1 (belongs to it) and add it to the total loss.

My question is: Given a sample that belongs to A, will Tensorflow optimize the parameters only for A and X (as I would like to) or will it also optimize the parameters for B, C?

Thanks

Comment: If the loss value that is computed with the parameters of, say, model B is then multiplied by 0, then the corresponding gradients for its variables will be zero. However, whether or not the variables are applied any update will depend on the optimization algorithm. Simple gradient descent would not change it, but any optimizer with momentum may still apply a change.

Comment: OK Thanks! I want to use the Adam algorithm for optimization. How would I achieve that the parameters of B and C won't change?

Comment: That's quite tricky, I think. A somewhat brute-force solution would be to add ops _after_ the optimization that restore the variables of models that shouldn't be touched to their values at the beginning of the run. However, even the internal variables of the optimizer would be updated, so Adam wouldn't be working quite as it is supposed to...